# How can I increase ID column manually in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I need to change default ID column to different number on Microsoft Lists(Sharepoint Lists) so, its now 633 but i need to increase to 1198. I just want the change the last entry to 1198, so it stars increasing from 1198.

is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Logically user do not have control over ID column. So not possible in direct way. Workaround. you create dummy items using script till it meets your desired ID number and delete those dummy items.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot Change this, Its by Product design, But as a workaround you can add some dummy items and delete the same, you may get the desired ID.
If still you want to keep the logic , I suggest to create a new column and update the ID, while retrieve the data , please query the created column and fetch the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to update the default ID column of a list in SharePoint online. **ID field is an auto-increase column and it's read-only**.

You could always recreate the list and add the items again in the proper order, or create a custom 'id' column to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I exported the list to excel. I added dummy items to excel until i match the number i needed then i imported the excel back and created a new list.

Thanks.